# Linking to simple internal link via react-router-dom dynamically through component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to simply just link to a different part of the same page. I can get this to work without using `<Link>` tags and just using `<a>` tags. However, I am trying to make a dynamic component that either outputs `<a>` if an internal link is passed to the component, or `<Link>` if not.

My code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <LinkedComponent buttonLink="#test" buttonText="Link 1" />
      {/* #test works */}
      <LinkedComponent buttonLink="/test" buttonText="Link 2" />
      {/* /test fails as <link> outputs (with lowercase l) */}
      where is link 2?
    </div>
  );
}

const LinkedComponent = ({ buttonLink, buttonText }) => {
  const samePageLink = buttonLink[0] === '#' ? true : false;
  const LinkTag = samePageLink ? 'a' : 'Link';

  return (
    <LinkTag
      {...(samePageLink ? { href: buttonLink } : { to: buttonLink })}
      className="cls"
    >
      {buttonText}
    </LinkTag>
  );
};
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9py7xc?file=src%2FApp.js

Does anyone know what's wrong here? Link 2 should also show.

I have also tried using `{React.createElement(LinkTag, { className: 'cls' }, buttonText)}`, but the same problem still occurs as it also outputs `<link>` tags incorrectly.

Note that on my actual real app (but for some reason not on the demo I have provided) I can resolve the issue by writing un-dry, verbose code like this:

```
  return (
    <>
      {samePageLink ? (
        <a href={buttonLink} className="cls">
          {buttonText}
        </a>
      ) : (
        <Link to={buttonLink} className="cls">
          {buttonText}
        </Link>
      )}
    </>
  );
```

But I do not want to write bad code like this. Does anyone know how to fix this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Link` must be a descendent of `Route`.
2. `"a"` and `"Link"` are string but `<a>` and `<Link>` are react compoent of  type `React.ReactElement`. Your solution does not work.

---

This should work if you need to use `<Link>`

```
 function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter basename={"/"}>
            <Routes>
                <Route path={"/"} element={<IndexPage />} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

const IndexPage = () => {
    return <div>
        <LinkedComponent buttonLink="#test" buttonText="Link 1" />
        {/* #test works */}
        <LinkedComponent buttonLink="/test" buttonText="Link 2" samePageLink={true} />
        {/* /test fails as <link> outputs (with lowercase l) */}
        where is link 2?
    </div>
}


const LinkedComponent = ({ buttonLink, buttonText, samePageLink = false }) => {
    if (samePageLink) {
        return <a href={buttonLink}>{buttonText}</a>
    }
    return  <Link to={buttonLink}>{buttonText}</Link>
};
```

You may not need to use `<Link>`

```
 function App() {
    return (
        <IndexPage />
    );
}

const IndexPage = () => {
    return <div>
        <LinkedComponent buttonLink="#test" buttonText="Link 1" />
        {/* #test works */}
        <LinkedComponent buttonLink="/test" buttonText="Link 2" samePageLink={true} />
        {/* /test fails as <link> outputs (with lowercase l) */}
        where is link 2?
    </div>
}


const LinkedComponent = ({ buttonLink, buttonText, samePageLink = false }) => {
    if (samePageLink) {
        return <a href={buttonLink}>{buttonText}</a>
    }
    return  <a href={buttonLink}>{buttonText}</a>
};
```

## Update

You can create a component like `Link`.

```
const LinkedComponent = ({ buttonLink, buttonText, samePageLink = false }) => {
    const A = samePageLink ? Anchor : Link
    return  <A to={buttonLink}>{buttonText}</A>
};

const Anchor = ({to, children}) => {
    return <a href={to}> {children} </a>
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, but is essentially the same as my verbose solution above. Is it possible to return a custom tag like `<LinkTag/>` instead of `<a>` or `<Link>`? Otherwise I will have to repeat the props like className and buttonText etc

Comment: Also, I'm surprised that react-router-dom's Link component doesn't work when linking to somewhere on the same page